# Public Cloud Virtual Machine - Restrict Uninstalling Packages

Tags: ubuntu, centos, amazon-web-services, azure, redhat

During the evaluation on public cloud(VMs) security product, Below question came into my mind. I would like to request your kind consultancy to fix this challenge

**Requirement**: Install a security agent on public cloud virtual machines.

**Challenge**: Unfortunately Root user or ec2-user(AWS), auzreuser(Azure) can uninstall these agents

**Question**
Is there a way that we can configure, in a way that any user in the system to prevent uninstalling/remove above agents only.

May I ask what are the possible approaches we have to achieve this problem ?

Thank you,

Comment: How is the security agent installed, via the OS, or by some sort of extension provided by the cloud platform?

Comment: @SamCogan Thanks, It is installed via OS